# How to impelment password check delay in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want all the login attempts to my web application to take no less than 1 second, to make brute force attack less feasible. If I just put something like this in my code:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000)
```

I expect that I become susceptible to a very simple ddos attack: just launch several dozen login requests to the site, and thread pool starvation will happen. (I don't believe that  Thread.Sleep returns thread to the thread pool, does it?)

What is the correct way to implement this feature?

Comment: Would you put the sleep function in the code unconditionally, or only if the login fails?  If the latter, it might not be effective against a brute force attack -- if the server takes more than a couple hundred ms to respond, it means the login was incorrect; the attacker wouldn't have to wait for your response.  An unconditional delay would prevent this, but would be noticable by legitimate users and could easily result in thread starvation. The other responses that were recommended would be effective in protecting against brute-force attacks without these issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could do instead of sleeping the thread (you're right to be concerned about starvation) is to have a sliding window based upon unsuccessful login attempts for a given username. You could store this in the in-memory cache and ignore login attempts for that username if the sliding window has not yet elapsed.

There's a decent blog post on one possible implementation of this here:

[Brute Force Protect Your Website](http://madskristensen.net/post/Brute-force-protect-your-website.aspx)

Comment: Yes, thank you, I was hoping to avoid the complexity of the lock-out solution with something simpler. Might well be I'm out of luck here and will have to go with the lock out.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be a lock out; The sliding window could simply be 1 second minimum. This would achieve your desired result mentioned in the original post. I mean, I guess it depends on your definition of lockout, but thats effectively what you'd be doing with a thread sleep too.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make brute force attacks less feasible, why don't you implement a lock-out (force a password reset) after (say) 3 incorrect login attempts to the same account with no intervening correct login?

If you need DDOS protection, I would handle that separately - quite possibly with something before the traffic gets to your web server to start with. It really depends on whether you'

I don't know whether there's a simple way of delaying a response asynchronously in ASP.NET at the moment. I'm expecting that with the async stuff coming in C# 5 and .NET 5, you'll be able to return a `Task<ActionResult>`, at which point you'll be able to write something like:

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
```

Comment: Hi Jon, thank you for taking time to respond. I'm not particularly worried about DDOS, it's just I don't want to make it simpler than "default". I agree that in general DDOS has to be handled separately. Lock-out increases number of support calls in general so it's desirable to avoid. Of course I could do temporary lock-out in the same manner Active Directory does, but it's a bit harder to implement. Making sure that the request does not take less than one second seems to look like much much simpler solution. Is this really such a bad idea?

Comment: @zespri: If you don't have *any* lockout then brute force can still be achieved in a trickling way (and it wouldn't have to be *too* trickly, if you didn't have much DDOS protection). I would really consider lockout - even if you push it up to (say) 10 bad logins and make it really clear on the login page. If someone has failed to log in successfully 10 times in a row, what's the chance they'll get it right on the 11th? You *could* make it temporary - which probably wouldn't make it *that* much harder, to be honest. Probably easier than getting an async delay working.